# Verify version of PDF and redownload new version

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am trying to build a Flutter/Dart procedure-app for my work as a CRNA. I am trying to make the app retrieve the pdf's from a server. Then display them in the app. The thing is I want to be able to publish new versions of the PDF and then download it. I am also trying to make them all searchable, but I am too new to programming to understand how I can do this, and what way is the best.

Any pointers and help is much appreciated!

Best regards,
Veritiaas

Comment: First, you should share the code you have. There is a package for this.
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Comment: At the moment I don't have a code for this problem, because I don't know what's the best way to handle this kind of issue. I don't know the terminology either for what I have described which makes it hard to find good tips/guides online. At the moment I only have a shell with login set to company e-mail verification and a journalfunction. I appreciate the suggestion of PDF-package, but I want to make the contents of the pdf searchable from the main-"window" of the app, and I think I need to parse the PDF to a "window", or am I in the wrong here?

Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it!

Comment: Now you can look at this. https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_text

Comment: I will try it out, thank you! Is it possible to use the PDFDocInfo info = doc.info; function to verify the file version? So if it's named Anesthesia v1.0, if it's v1.1 it can download the latest version and delete the previous? I think I can code something like that, at least I will give it a try!